# Cannot set password of user postgres despite running successful ALTER USER WITH PASSWORD query

Tags: postgresql

I have a brew-installed version of Postgres 12.3 running on my mac.

`\du` shows two users:

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 facthna   | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
```

This command is all it takes to log me in:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Note it doesn't require a password.

Once logged in, I have tried this:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'blah';
```

Which responds with:

```
ALTER ROLE
```

However logging out and logging back in still doesn't require a password.

I have also tried restarting the Postgres service but this makes no difference.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to check your [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) which specifies what origins of connection to which database require what types of authorisation for which user.
To locate **pg_hba.conf** file you can issue this command from within psql:

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

If upon inspection of the file you find something along the lines of

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

It means all local connections are trusted and therefore you're just skipping the password prompt when connecting locally.

To force the database to require the password, replace *trust* with *md5* for the databases, users and origins of connection where you want this behaviour, like so:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

And then ask your database to apply the changes:

> The pg_hba.conf file is read on start-up and when the main server
> process receives a SIGHUP signal. If you edit the file on an active
> system, you will need to signal the postmaster (using pg_ctl reload,
> calling the SQL function pg_reload_conf(), or using kill -HUP) to make
> it re-read the file.